# Declaration of PDOextension::query($query, $data = null) must be compatible with PDO::query

Tags: php, pdo

I'm doing PHP PDO project now. Updating the server from PHP 7 to PHP 8.2. As I converting, I'm experiencing error on this code:

```
function query($query,$data=null) {
    $stmt = $this->prepare($query);
    if ($data)
      return $stmt->execute($data);
    else
      return $stmt->execute();
}
```

I got this error:
Fatal error: Declaration of PDOextension::query($query, $data = null) must be compatible with PDO::query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, mixed ...$fetchModeArgs): PDOStatement|false in /home1/kingdomofpets/public_html/members/lib/classes/PDOextension.php on line 30

The line 30 is function query($query,$data=null) {

Is there I need to change on the code or somewhere? I hope I got help from all of you guys.  Thank you!